# regex: string with optional parts

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse some docstrings.

An example docstrings is:

```
Test if a column field is larger than a given value
    This function can also be called as an operator using the '>' syntax

    Arguments:
        - DbColumn self
        - string or float value: the value to compare to
            in case of string: lexicographic comparison
            in case of float: numeric comparison
    Returns:
        DbWhere object
```

Both the `Arguments` and `Returns` parts are optional. I want my regex to return as groups the description (first lines), the `Arguments` part (if present) and the `Returns` part (if present).

The regex I have now is:

```
m = re.search('(.*)(Arguments:.*)(Returns:.*)', s, re.DOTALL)
```

and works in case all three parts are present but fails as soon as `Arguments` or the `Returns`parts are not available. I have tried several variations with the non-greedy modifiers like `??`but to no avail.

**Edit:**  When the `Arguments` and `Returns` parts are present, I actually would only like to match the text after `Arguments:` and `Returns:` respectively.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the order always fixed? I. e., is `Arguments` always after the standard text and before `Returns`?

Comment: Yes, the order is always fixed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try with:

```
re.search('^(.*?)(Arguments:.*?)?(Returns:.*)?$', s, re.DOTALL)
```

Just making the second and third groups *optional* by appending a `?`, and making the qualifiers of the first two groups *non-greedy* by (again) appending a `?` on them (yes, confusing).

Also, if you use the non-greedy modifier on the first group of the pattern, it'll match the shortest possible substring, which for `.*` is the empty string. You can overcome this by adding the end-of-line character (`$`) at the end of the pattern, which forces the first group to match as few characters as possible to satisfy the pattern, i.e. the whole string when there's no `Arguments` and no `Returns` sections, and everything before those sections, when present.

**Edit:** OK, if you just want to capture the text *after* the `Arguments:` and `Returns:` tokens, you'll have to tuck in a couple more groups. We're not going to use all of the groups, so naming them —with the `<?P<name>` notation (*another* question mark, argh!)— is starting to make sense:

```
>>> m = re.search('^(?P<description>.*?)(Arguments:(?P<arguments>.*?))?(Returns:(?P<returns>.*))?$', s, re.DOTALL)
>>> m.groupdict()['description']
"Test if a column field is larger than a given value\n    This function can also be called as an operator using the '>' syntax\n\n    "
>>> m.groupdict()['arguments']
'\n        - DbColumn self\n        - string or float value: the value to compare to\n            in case of string: lexicographic comparison\n            in case of float: numeric comparison\n    '
>>> m.groupdict()['returns']
'\n        DbWhere object'
>>>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! How would you modify the regex if, for the optional parts, I only want to match the text after `Arguments` and `Returns`?

Comment: Something like `re.search('^(.*?)(Arguments:(.*?))?(Returns:(.*))?$', doc, re.DOTALL)` works, but I don't care for the second and fourth group it returns.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Just name the groups and forget about `groups()`, use `groupdict()` instead.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to match the text after optional `Arguments:` and `Returns:` sections, *AND* you don't want to use `(?P<name>...)` to name your capture groups, you can also use, `(?:...)`, the non-capturing version of regular parentheses.

The regex would look like this:

```
m = re.search('^(.*?)(?:Arguments:(.*?))?(?:Returns:(.*?))?$', doc, re.DOTALL)
#                     ^^                  ^^
```

According to the Python3 [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> `(?:...)`
>
> A non-capturing version of regular parentheses. Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, but the substring matched by the group cannot be retrieved after performing a match or referenced later in the pattern.