# Python - error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a string that looks like:

```
phrase = '5 hampshire road bradford on avon avon dinas powys powys north somerset hampshire avon'
```

I want to return a new string with certain words removed, only if they are not preceded by certain other words.

For example, the words I want to remove are:

```
c_out = ["avon", "powys", "somerset","hampshire"]
```

*Only if they do not follow*:

```
c_except = ["on\s","dinas\s"]
```

Note: There could be multiple instances of words within `c_out`, and multiple instances of words within `c_except`.

Individually I tried for `'on\s'`:

```
phrase = '5 hampshire road bradford on avon avon dinas powys powys north somerset hampshire avon'

regexp1 = re.compile(r'(?<!on\s)(avon|powys|somerset|hampshire)')
print("1st Result: ", regexp1.sub('', phrase))
1st Result:  '5  road bradford on avon avon dinas   north'
```

This correctly ignores the first `'avon'`, as it is preceded by `'on\s'`, it correctly removes the third `'avon'`, **but** it ignores the second `'avon'` (which it does not remove).

In the same way, for `'dinas\s'`:

```
phrase = '5 hampshire road bradford on avon avon dinas powys powys north somerset hampshire avon'

regexp2 = re.compile(r'(?<!dinas\s)(avon|powys|somerset|hampshire)')
print("2nd Result: ", regexp2.sub('', phrase))
2nd Result:  '5  road bradford on   dinas powys  north '
```

This correctly ignores the first `'powys'` and removes the second (note the double space between `'... powys  north'`.

I tried to combine the two expressions by doing:

```
regexp3 = re.compile(r'((?!on\s)|(?!dinas\s))(avon|powys|somerset|hampshire)')
print("3rd Result: ", regexp3.sub('', phrase))
3rd Result:  5  road bradford on   dinas   north
```

This incorrectly removed every word, and completely ignored `'on\s'` or `'dinas\s'`.

Then I tried:

```
regexp4 = re.compile(r'(?<!on\s|dinas\s)(avon|powys|somerset|hampshire)')
print("4th Result: ", regexp4.sub('', phrase))
```

And got:

```
error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
```

I want to end up with:

```
Result: '5  road bradford on avon dinas powys  north     '
```

I have had a look at:

[Why is this not a fixed width pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333200/why-is-this-not-a-fixed-width-pattern)
[Python Regex Engine - "look-behind requires fixed-width pattern" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089922/python-regex-engine-look-behind-requires-fixed-width-pattern-error)
[regex: string with optional parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018947/regex-string-with-optional-parts)

But to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

---

From comments:

```
regexp5 = re.compile(r'(?<!on\s)(?<!dinas\s)(avon|powys|somerset|hampshire)')
print("5th Result: ", regexp5.sub('', phrase))
5th Result:  5  road bradford on avon avon dinas powys  north
```

Again this misses the second avon.

Comment: Replace `(?<!on\s|dinas\s)` with `(?<!on\s)(?<!dinas\s)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That ignores the second '`avon'` -> `5th result = "5  road bradford on avon avon dinas powys  north   "`

Comment: Then use a word boundary - `r'(?<!\bon\s)(?<!\bdinas\s)'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This gives me the original error `error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern`. (See 6th regex)

Comment: See https://ideone.com/BSEojT. No error, and the result is as expected.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ... [tests and finds it works exactly correct] Thank you!  I'll gladly accept if you post as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are 2 approaches that will solve the issue:

## Chained Lookbehinds

Convert an alternation based lookbehind into several negative lookbehinds since the logical relations between them will be the same (that of AND):

```
import re
phrase = '5 hampshire road bradford on avon avon dinas powys powys north somerset hampshire avon'
c_except = [r"on\s",r"dinas\s"]
c_out = ["avon", "powys", "somerset","hampshire"]
rx = r"(?<!\b{0})({1})".format(r")(?<!\b".join(c_except), "|".join(c_out))
print(re.sub(rx, "", phrase))
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/BSEojT).

## Capturing Approch

Capture what you need to keep and match only what you need to remove, and use `\1` backreference to restore Group 1 value:

```
import re
phrase = '5 hampshire road bradford on avon avon dinas powys powys north somerset hampshire avon'
c_except = [r"on\s+",r"dinas\s+"]
c_out = ["avon", "powys", "somerset","hampshire"]
rx = r"(\b(?:{0})(?:{1}))|(?:{1})".format(r"|".join(c_except), "|".join(c_out))
print(re.sub(rx, r"\1", phrase))
```

See [another Python demo](https://ideone.com/RL7wfH).

Note that this approach is favorable since you may use variable width patterns inside `c_except`.

The regex will look like

```
(\b(?:on\s+|dinas\s+)(?:avon|powys|somerset|hampshire))|(?:avon|powys|somerset|hampshire)
```

It will match `on` or `dinas` as whole words due to the `\b` word boundary, and then any of the terms you need to remove and since that part is wrapped into a capturing group, you may refer to the capture with `\1` backreference. In all other contexts, the `c_out` terms will be removed with the `|(?:avon|powys|somerset|hampshire)` pattern.

NOTE: The `\1` replacement will work in Python 3.5+. For older versions, and Python 2.x, you need to replace it with a lambda:

```
re.sub(rx, lambda m: m.group(1) if m.group(1) else "", phrase)
```

Comment: Thank you - this works exactly. Really appreciate having 2 approaches. Thanks again, C